# Laravel redirect controller to controller empty $this variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

We want to pass data from controller to another controller in Laravel (framework). In our Controller.php we got a middleware code in the __construct function, which sets a environment and person.

Code in Controller.php

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->environment = session()->get('environment');
        $this->person = session()->get('person');

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

In a different controller we pass 2 parameters (Request data) and (id of data) to another controller function. We tried many ways for pass data. On this moment we lost our $this data like environment and person, the variables environment and person are exists but empty.

We tried with:

```
  $postController = new \App\Http\Controllers\Publication\Post\IndexController();
  $postController->duplicate($request, data_get($publication, 'id'));
```

Or

```
app('App\Http\Controllers\Publication\Post\IndexController')->duplicate($request, data_get($publication, 'id'))
```

In Post\IndexController@duplicate we lose our $this data (empty).
We tried to get data like $this->enviroment but this variables are empty.

Anyone has any idea how to pass data with the variables filled by the middleware?

Comment: First of all calling controller inside an other controller is a bad practice !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the power of Container

Code in `Controller.php`

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        app()->instance('person', session()->get('person'));
        app()->instance('environment', session()->get('environment'));

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

In another controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class DupeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        dd(app('person'));
    }
}
```

Just make sure if the "another controller" has it's own constructor, call the parent constructor, you your 'person' and 'environment' instance would be available in that controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class DupeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // DO MAGIC
    }

    public function index()
    {
        dd(app('person'));
    }
}
```

But I gotta tell you the truth, this is a bad practice. I just want to show you that something bad like this is possible. Try another approach like service injection to the controller using dependency injection technique and mark that service as a singleton, so container will resolve the same instance for every resolution (one instance per request).